# Hibernate session createSQLQuery

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I wrote function that table klienci will join with the same table. I checked statement in sqlDeveloper and it's returns the correct value but here I have twice values ​​from the first table on the other not (variables klient1 and klient2 have the same values). There is no Foreign Key. Maybe someone sees what I did wrong?

```
public List<Klienci[]> getAllKlienci() {

    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Query query = session.createSQLQuery("select k1.id, k1.nr_klienta,"
            + " k1.nr_klienta_niekod, k1.nazwa_klienta, k2.id,"
            + " k2.nr_klienta, k2.nr_klienta_niekod, k2.nazwa_klienta"
            + " from klienci k1 "
            + "left join klienci k2 on k1.nr_klienta_niekod = k2.nr_klienta");


    List<Object[]> klienci = query.list();
    // Transformacja w List<Klienci[]> 

    List<Klienci[]> returnList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Object[] klient : klienci) {
        Klienci[] retunArray = new Klienci[2];

        Klienci klient1 = new Klienci();

        klient1.setId( ((BigDecimal)klient[0]).longValue() );
        klient1.setNrKlienta( ((BigDecimal)klient[1]).longValue() );
        klient1.setNrKlientaNiekod( ((BigDecimal)klient[2]).longValue() );
        klient1.setNazwaKlienta( (String) klient[3] );

        Klienci klient2 = new Klienci();

        klient2.setId( ((BigDecimal)klient[4]).longValue() );
        klient2.setNrKlienta( ((BigDecimal)klient[5]).longValue() );
        klient2.setNrKlientaNiekod( ((BigDecimal)klient[6]).longValue() );
        klient2.setNazwaKlienta( (String) klient[7] );

        retunArray[0] = klient1;
        retunArray[1] = klient2;

        returnList.add(retunArray);

    }

    return returnList;
}
```

Comment: the question is why use sqlquery when you have hql or criteria, with a self-join query?

Comment: because there is not foreign key

Comment: and why not? you create your schema with hibernate? you can map it even if is not a fk

Comment: can you give me example how can I do self-join using criteria?

Comment: if you map in your class you only have to do `FROM Table`